# Arbitrarily rotated quadrilateralized spherical cube projection in GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system

I want to convert some maps of the Earth using the quadrilateralized spherical cube projection. Using [this tutorial](https://proj.org/en/5.2/operations/projections/qsc.html?highlight=quadril) I were able to make the maps in which South and North Poles are positioned in the centers of squares. But I were unable to make the map that is differently rotated, e.g. when the South and North Poles are on the angles or on the edges of the squares. Is it possible to do this using GDAL?

Comment: Take a look at this transformation supported by PROJ: [General Oblique Transformation](https://proj.org/en/5.2/operations/projections/ob_tran.html?highlight=rotated%20pole)

I haven't used it so I'm unwilling to make an answer out of it.